# how to connect pycharm to python?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I have installed pycharm. I have installed python version 2022.
I need to know how to connect Pycharm with Python. I am new in this, so not sure.

Once I opened Pycharm I saw already that my project was showing in Pycharm. It prompted me to select trust. I trusted the content and it was showing me the selection for 2 versions of Python. I was not sure if that is the way to connect, or is there another way to connect ?

Comment: are you using windows ? and what versions of python does it show

Comment: Hi, I was able to connect it. However, I needed to activate safety on the workspace as it was blocked